# reading and discarding lines

Tags: linux, bash, filter

I have a question about a problem that I have to solve, I have my lines in this way:

Input

```
GTEX-1117F-0003-SM-58Q7G
GTEX-1117F-0003-SM-5DWSB
GTEX-111CU-0826-SM-5EGIJ
GTEX-111CU-0926-SM-5EGIK
GTEX-ZZPU-2726-SM-5NQ8O
GTEX-ZZPU-2626-SM-5E45Y
K-562-SM-2AXVE
K-562-SM-26GMQ
```

I have another file that tells me that the first letters are the "patients" (e.g. `GTEX-1117F`, `GTEX-111CU`, `GTEX-ZZPU`, and `K-562`).

I need a unique code to know, which patient has the most samples?

Thus, I need to know for example how many samples has the "patient" `GTEX-1117F`, in this case I have 2.

Output required

```
GTEX-1117F 2
GTEX-111CU 2
GTEX-ZZPU 2
K-562 2
```

And then I need to know the "patient" with more samples (e.g. `K-562 140`).

Comment: Are the patiens' IDs always the two first words separated by `-` on each line? If so, the other file seems not needed.

Comment: Yes, they are. The identifiers are always like this GTEX-1117F, but with different denominations after - , and for the last one is K instead of GTEX.

Comment: Your title says something about "discarding lines". Could you possible elaborate on that?

Comment: What happens if there are two top equal results? Should both be printed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give a different sample so the count is more visible:

```
GTEX-1117F-0003-SM-58Q7G
GTEX-1117F-0003-SM-58Q7G
GTEX-1117F-0003-SM-5DWSB
GTEX-111CU-0826-SM-5EGIJ
GTEX-111CU-0926-SM-5EGIK
GTEX-ZZPU-2726-SM-5NQ8O
GTEX-ZZPU-2626-SM-5E45Y
K-562-SM-2AXVE
```

The command, assuming the patient id is in the format `string-string`:

```bsh
$ cut -d'-' -f1,2 file | uniq -c | awk -F' ' '{ print $2,$1}' | sort -rk2 | head -1
GTEX-1117F 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `cut` to extract the first two dash-delimited fields on each line, sort the result of that, and count the number of times each unique string occurs:

```
$ cut -d '-' -f 1,2 file | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | head
   2 GTEX-1117F
   2 GTEX-111CU
   2 GTEX-ZZPU
   2 K-562
```

This also passes the data through `sort -n` to sort on the numbers and uses `head` to get the top results.

Comment: Thank your for your answer. It worked

Comment: Depending on the contents of the second file, `grep -Fwf file2` might be appropriate to add to the pipeline.

Comment: @glennjackman It is not clear what the purpose of the other file is.

Comment: The problem I see with these approaches (my answer is very similar to yours) is what happens if there are two top equal results, then I guess both should be printed.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity Since the user did not specify how the solution should be have in this case, and since they provided an example where _all_ results are equal, I'm assuming that there may have to be some tweaking tho the pipeline's final stage. I'm using `head`, which will give the top 10 results, while you simply discard the results that have high count as the top, but fails o sort on the first line.

Comment: @Kusalananda The final part of the question is "And then I need to know the "patient" with more samples (e.g. K-562 140).". I guess that's why OP's accepted mine.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity (shrug) We may never know. The question is vague and you happened to hit closest to whatever the user think they wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Calling only awk and avoiding the delay of sorting, you may use:

```
awk -F- '{c[$1"-"$2]++}END{for (i in c){print i,c[i]}}' file
```

Comment: +1 I'm bad at awk, started with the same approach `awk -F- '{c[$1"-"$2]++}` but didn't know how to continue.

Answer (score 0):

How about starting with

```
$ for F in `cat patients`; do echo -n "$F " ; grep "^$F" records | wc -l; done
GTEX-1117F 2
GTEX-111CU 2
GTEX-ZZPU 2
K-562 2
$
```